# Why this gives min as 10 and max as 7

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, exception, while-loop

for, this code below:
(Indented to output max and min value from the given input, which ends and prints the values on typing done and handle exception for string inputs)

```
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        try:
            numb = input("Enter a number: ")
            if num == "done":
                break
            print(num)
            numb = int(num)
            if largest is None or largest < num:
                largest = num
            elif smallest is None or smallest > num:
                smallest = num
        except ValueError:
            print("Please, enter only numbers.")
    

    print("Maximum", largest)
    print("Minimum", smallest)
```

on entering input values as 7, 2, bob, 10, 4 and done;
why am I getting
Minimum as 10
Maximum as 7

instead when I changed numb to num I got the correct values like
Minimum as 2
Maximum as 10

please explain on how exactly numb get min as 10 and max as 7.
( I know that I can correct it by putting numb in comparison if loop but I rather want to know on how exactly this particular case gets minimum as 10 and maximum as 7)

Comment: You didn't declare the `name` as a variable but you're checking with `"done"`. How it will compare?

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume your code originally had `num = input(...)` instead of `numb = input(...)`.

With `largest < num` and `largest = num`, you're working with **strings**. Comparison works *lexicographically*, i.e. `'a' < 'b'`, `'10' < '7'`, `'2' < 'c'`. Hence, your code will find the largest and smallest values based on *lexicographical order*.

The proper order of your input would be:

```
10, 2, 4, 7, bob
```

But `bob` was excluded since `int(num)` would raise an exception. Here, your min was 10 and your max was 7.

Now, with `largest < numb`, you're working with **integers**. And these are ordered as you would normally expect them to be:

```
2, 4, 7, 10
```

This gives you the result you expect.